# Why do the pointers in my array point to the same string?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, getline

I'm trying to understand why an issue is happening. I have a file, from which I read several lines:

```
char *array_slave[128];

int i = 0;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    if (strstr(line, "X") != NULL)
    {
        array_slave[i] = line;
        printf("%s\n",array_slave[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

After this cycle, I know that `array_slave` contains 32 lines:

```
size_t array_length(char *ptr[])
{
    size_t i=0;
    while(ptr[i]!=NULL){
        //printf("%d\n", i);
        //printf("%s\n",ptr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return i;

}
```

Now, I simply want to print the last 4 elements of `array_slave`. Anyway, I noticed that it prints always the same line:

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
    printf("%s\n", array_slave[i]);
}
```

I think that this happens because, in the first cycle, the `i++` operation shifts the pointer, so now it is in a memory address that is not of my interest. How can I return the original position of `array_slave`? I want to point to `array_slave[0]`, `array_slave[1]` and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Because they are both pointing to same `line`.
`array_slave[i] = line;` stores the same address at the `ith` location for each `i`. The memory pointed by `line` is overwritten with new content each time. You should copy the contents of line to a new place and store the address of that place in the `array_slave` array.

Comment: To be noted, too: *Unless* re-allocation occurs because of previous line being too short – in which case the pointers stored previously get *invlidated*!

Answer (score 1):

> *After this cicle, I know that `array_slave` contains 32 lines*

That is not entirely accurate, it contains 32 pointers to char that will all *point to*<sup>1</sup> the address of `line`, which is in itself a pointer to char that will be pointing to a unique memory location, it will not change where it's pointing to along the loop, what will change is what is stored in that memory location, which is the read line in that particular iteration.

---

So with the above information you can see that the pointers stored in `array_slave` will all point to `line` and print whatever is in there,  repeatedly in your cycle, and what `line` *contains*<sup>2</sup> is the last line you read from the file.

What you need to do is to copy the content of `line` to `array_slave[i]` in each iteration:

```
//...
if (strstr(line, "X") != NULL)
{
    strcpy(array_slave[i], line); //<---
    printf("%s\n",array_slave[i]);
    i++;
}
//...
```

---

<sup>1 - Contain the address of</sup>
<sup>2 - Points to</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the solution proposed by the previous answers the problem could also be solved by setting `line` to NULL after copying the pointer to `slave_array`:

```
char *array_slave[128];

int i = 0;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    if (strstr(line, "X") != NULL)
    {
        array_slave[i] = line;
        line = NULL;  // HERE
        printf("%s\n",array_slave[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

That will cause `getline()` to `malloc()` a new buffer when it's called the next time.
Be aware you have to `free()` each `array_slave[i]` when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Adding (lately, for late readers) yet another approach: Just skip this intermediate variable `line` *entirely* and read into the array directly; for this purpose, it must be initialised appropriately, though:

```
char *array_slave[128] = { NULL };
```

which then allows reading the lines as

```
getline(array_slave + i, &len, fp)
```